# Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I previously was using Android Studio v2.3 to Make Module and it was ok. Now I changed to Android Studio v3.0, when I trying to Make Module, it shows the error below:

```
Error:Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.getBundle(AndroidJpsBundle.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.message(AndroidJpsBundle.java:32)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.runAaptCompiler(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:971)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.doBuild(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.build(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1263)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:940)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:903)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:736)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:384)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:192)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:295)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Is it showing any packages to install ?

Comment: nope, not showing any packages to install.

Comment: @vincent did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I ran into the same issue in v3.0 -- but via a different vector. I got the error when I tried to run code without properly importing it into my gradle project. I rebuilt the project and now it works fine.

Answer (score 22):

I ran into the same issue and this worked for me so let me know how it goes.

1. Right click on your project and open up `Module Settings`
2. Click facets.
3. Add `Android-Gradle` and apply.
4. Close and reopen project and rebuild.

Comment: I don't see anything saying "Android-Grandle" in the facets Module settings (using 3.0.1)

Comment: Sorry that I didn't respond earlier, was spending time with friends/family for the holidays. What do you see? I tried setting up on a new machine and downloaded version 2.3.3 https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html which was suggested after reading other posts and had zero issues. Maybe give that a crack as well.

Comment: This wasn't the solution for me, as it was not a Gradle based project. It did however point me in the right direction! I noticed there was a Gradle-aware make entry in the build config, which I removed to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 10):

1. backup AndroidStudio3.0\plugins\android\lib\jps\*.jar
2. Copy AndroidStudio2.3.3\plugins\android\lib\jps\*.jar to 
   AndroidStudio3.0\plugins\android\lib\jps\*.jar

Comment: It definitely works. Download 2.3.2 if you haven't one.

Comment: Yes, reverting to 2.3.3 in its entirety also fixes this problem.  Working versions available from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html whichever way you go with.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I did not open the correct project directory in Android Studio. I have a Grande project, but when opened [Project Folder] -> [Android] -> [App] as an existing project in Android Studio, it solved the problem for me!

When you open as existing project the [Project Folder] only in Android Studio and try to compile and generate the APK, it will show this error above: Error:Android Source Generator....

So, please ensure you import the correct directory of your Android Project ;-)