# Error on opening a Project created on Android Studio 2.3 in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-version

I'm currently using Android Studio 3.0.1. When I try to open a project that has been developed in Android Studio 2.3 I encountered with the following error,

```
Error: Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_IN
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_IN
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.getBundle(AndroidJpsBundle.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.message(AndroidJpsBundle.java:32)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.runAaptCompiler(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:971)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.doBuild(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.build(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1263)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:940)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:903)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:736)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:384)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:192)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:295)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have referred the answers to the previously asked question with the same problem. But those answers don't work for me.

Is it really the problem is related to the Android Studio versions or something else? Kindly provide me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: try to change gradle version to 3.0.1, try to clean and rebuild your project,

Comment: There is no gradle in the project.

Comment: this one help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45365854/android-source-generator-error-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-messages-androi

Comment: Thanks @KuLdipPaTel . I have already referred these solution but it doesn't works for me so only i have posted my own question for further solutions.