# Android Studio can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.2

I backed up the directory of my project which was developed in `android-studio-2.2.2` and try to import it by selecting `Open an existing Android Studio Project` from welcome page of Android Studio after installing `android-studio-3.1.2`. But building failed by this error message:

```
Error:Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
```

How I can solve this problem?

**Note**: Previously I saw these questions, bot no one is solved yet, so I posted a new question for further possible approaches:

- [Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45365854/1043882)
- [Error on opening a Project created on Android Studio 2.3 in Android Studio 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49404098/1043882)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after awhile, I did not find any solution and was forced to create a new empty project and move files to that manually.