# Import from Eclipse to Android Studio: Can't find bundle messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale pl_PL

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I've just imported Eclipse project into Android Studio, and it resulted the above message when building.

I am deving a simple Android app without any framework like Spring/Hibernate and I am not using `ResourceBundle` anywhere (I am using `res/values/strings.xml` solution).

My project has a dapendency of Google Play services, which by the look contains some references to the `ResourceBundle` class.

The other issue is that I cannot resolve any class from ads namespace, like `AdView`: 
`import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;` This sounds like it's related to the original issue.

```
Error:Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale pl_PL
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale pl_PL
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.getBundle(AndroidJpsBundle.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.message(AndroidJpsBundle.java:32)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.runAaptCompiler(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:971)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.doBuild(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.build(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1246)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:923)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:995)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:886)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:719)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:371)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:308)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:235)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also I am not using gradle as it blows out my whole project properties, from unknown reasons.

Comment: `"Also I am not using `gradle`"` well what are you doing ? explain (you mean you using `jetbrains` witch is **NOT** `Android Sudio` as your tag implies)?`Gradle` is the default **supported**  build mechanism (alongside [Android ANT](https://www.thisisant.com/developer/ant/ant-in-android)).

Comment: `IntelliJ IDEA` == `jetbrains` (also use by  `Android Studio` in *modified* form.

Comment: @JonGoodwin Like I've mentioned above, I've imported project from Eclipse, so it already had depedencies moved over. I am using the latest Android Studio, gradle isn't required to set a dependency.

Comment: You imported it , but did it work ? **`"`gradle` isn't required to set a dependency"** * (really)?)so how you build it* ? *Gradle builds it*,set the dependencies , dependencies are required, we are done, simples. You not got them moved over if `gradle` don't *know* about them.

Comment: I have modules/libs dependencies set in Project Settings, they should be compiled at the same time when app is build, some graphics: https://pasteboard.co/HqZjz4D.png

Comment: clearly you need to break it down, bit by bit in your mind, things don't work in big blocks, always tiny complications appear, as you get more experienced, they take less brain power and you fix them automatically.

Comment: import is not perfect, you need to fix things, Your being obtuse show your working (code/script)

Comment: Dude you need to use Gradle for building the project, the error you are getting has to be a cause of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the wild I've never once seen a 100% effective import tool for developers.**

Instead of trying to import the app spend the time to familiarize with the new environment by creating the same app in the new environment.  Most of it will be side by side copy and paste.

Comment: This is the correct answer, as gradle turned out to be a required tool for setting dependencies (although there is no such information about that on the Android Studio guide).

Answer (score 0):

If your project is using Bazel https://bazel.build/ you might want to try using a lower version of Android Studio. It was mentioned here that they don't support AS 3.0:

https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/issues/118

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9185-bazel

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, there are two answers to this error, as outlined in:
[Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45365854/android-source-generator-error-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-messages-androi)

[Downgrade to Android Studio 2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46966379/718291) or [Install Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47974023/718291). I suggest you install Gradle and then search for a solution to *whatever problems you have with that* (including, perhaps, another question here).